# XSLT templates for creating missing elements confict with each other

Tags: xml, xslt

I use XSLT transformation to add elements `configuration` and `status` to my XML data in case one or both of them are missing. I'd like to use independent templates to handle each of the these, but it seems only one of the template takes effect.

Source data:

```
<data>
  <environment>
    <id>test</id>
    <details>Detail info for environment...</details>
  </environment>
  <default_conf>abcd1234</default_conf>
  <default_status>1</default_status>
</data>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <!-- identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 <!-- if configuration not given, create it with the value of default_conf -->
 <xsl:template match="data[not(configuration)]">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <!--xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/-->
       <configuration><xsl:value-of select="default_conf"/></configuration>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- if status not given, create it with the value of default_status -->
 <xsl:template match="data[not(status)]">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     <!--xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/-->
     <status><xsl:value-of select="default_status"/></status>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the result XML only the  element is created, but not the  element. What's wrong with the transformation templates and how to correct it?

Please note that I need to pass also the `default_conf` and `default status` elements, so I'm not looking to rename these elements.

Desired output:

```
<data>
  <environment>
    <id>test</id>
    <details>Detail info for environment...</details>
  </environment>
  <default_conf>abcd1234</default_conf>
  <default_status>1</default_status>
  <configuration>abcd1234</configuration>
  <status>1</status>
</data>
```

Comment: It is difficult to handle that with two different templates matching the same element, unless you run two transformation steps e.g. store the result of the first element addition in a variable and then push that through another processing. That is rather easy in XSLT 2 or later but in XSLT 1 any variable would be a result tree fragment and you need to use `exsl:node-set` or similar to convert it to a node-set. As an alternative you could consider to add checks with e.g. `<xsl:if test="not(status)"><status>...</status></xsl:if>` and similarly for the other element in a single template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT,

> A node is processed by finding all the template rules with patterns that match the node, and choosing the best amongst them;
> https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Processing-Model

When both `configuration` and `status` are missing, you have two templates that match the same node, with the same priority. This is an error:

> An XSLT processor may signal the error; if it does not signal the error, it must recover by choosing, from amongst the matching template rules that are left, the one that occurs last in the stylesheet.
> https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#conflict

The simple solution is to use a single template with two `xsl:if` instructions to add each missing node. Otherwise you would need to use not two, but three templates - and make sure the added template takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k, that helped me design the solution as a single template with an if statement for each optional element.